# Command to separate nested brackets over multiple lines

Tags: substitute, formatting

I am looking for a language-agnostic way to convert something like this:

```
this(is, a, line(of, things))
```

to this:

```
this(
    is,
    a,
    line(
        of,
        things
    )
)
```

I can handle the non-nested case with this ugly key sequence:

```
vip:s/(/(\r    <CR>vip:s/)$/\r)<CR>vip:s/, /,\r    /g<CR>"
```

I do believe with some elbow grease I could put together a function to do this in lua or vimscript, but I am just checking here to see if anybody already likes to format their code in this way and has an established approach for doing this.

I say language agnostic but this is mostly for R code. I've stopped using the R language LSP server as it seemed pretty slow, so a non-LSP approach would be ideal.

Comment: This seems like a `:h cindent` problem.  I didn't quite grasp it so can't help off the top of my head.  Maybe skim through the doc of cindent?

Comment: Thank you, going through cindent options has helped make it much easier for code to automatically be indented correctly as I write things out. The answer by romainl was very helpful in converting old nested code to the appropriate format and together, things are going much smoother!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to improvise in two steps:

```
:s/[(),]\n\@!/&\r/g
:'[,norm ==
```

or as a one-liner:

```
:s/[(),]\n\@!/&\r/g|'[,norm ==
```

where:

- we substitute every `(`, `)`, or `,` in the current line with itself followed by a newline, unless it is followed by a newline,
- and we indent the text that was changed.

If you really need to do that often, turn the command above into a mapping:

```
" in after/ftplugin/r.vim
nnoremap <buffer> <key> <Cmd>s/[(),]\n\@!/&\r/g\|'[,norm ==<CR>
```

Now, the real *idiomatic* approach is to use `:help gq` with a proper `:help 'formatprg'` or `:help 'formatexpr'`. The simple command above has a very limited scope so it is easy to extrapolate a `formatexpr` from it:

```
" in after/ftplugin/r.vim
function! FormatexprExample()
    let l1 = v:lnum
    let l2 = (v:lnum + v:count) - 1
    execute l1 .. ',' .. l2 .. 's/[(),]\n\@!/&\r/g'
    '[,.normal! ==
    return 0
endfunction
setlocal formatexpr=FormatexprExample()
```

A proper `formatexpr` is never that simple, though.

Comment: Thank you! There's a lot for me to learn from this post and it'll take some time before I totally wrap my head around it.The substitution you provided seems to give something ever so slightly different in that it doesn't place the nested closing brackets on their own line. I've adapted it a little:

vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>so", "vip:s/)/\\r&/g<CR>vip:s/[(,]\\n\\@!/&\\r/g<CR>vip<ESC>vgq")

and that command now exactly achieves the target in the original post. When I have a little more time I'm looking forward to exploring the formatexpr approach.